# Extensions don't load in ipynb

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've downloaded a couple of extensions in VSCode and enabled them globally, but they're not applied in my ipynb files. I've tried to disable and reenable them, as well as restart VSCode.

[image: Image of VSCode]

Would any of you have an idea of why?

Comment: Not all extensions support all types of files, did you check the extensions what files are supported? your Jupiter notebook files probably need their own extensions

Comment: I've reopened Vscode, and now they load in .py files. Thank you for your help. :-)